# Rich ContextMenu does not get rendered

Tags: javascript, richfaces, contextmenu

I have a form with search criteria and a commandButton which triggers the search:

```
<h:form id="search_criteria">
     ...
 <a4j:commandButton id="commandButton" value="Search"
                actionListener="#{searchBean.searchActionListener}"
                render="@form, search_results_form_node,search_results_form_service" />
</form>
```

According to the results, a new form (search_results_form_node) appears with an extendedDataTable, which on left click renders another form (search_results_form_service) and on right click renders a contextMenu.

```
<h:form id="search_results_form_node">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="node_outputpanel">
        <rich:panel id="node_panel"
                    rendered="#{not searchBean.insufficientCriteria}">
            <h:outputText value="#{lbl.default_no_data_found}"
                          rendered="#{searchBean.isSearchResultNodeListEmpty}" />
            <rich:extendedDataTable id="node_table"
                                    value="#{searchBean.nodeList}" var="nod" iterationStatusVar="it"
                                    rows="12" rendered="#{not empty searchBean.nodeList}"
                                    selectionMode="single"
                                    selection="#{searchBean.selectedNodeCollection}">
                <a4j:ajax execute="@form" event="selectionchange"
                          listener="#{searchBean.nodeSelectionListener}"
                          render="search_results_form_service, panelGrid, tree_form, tree">
                </a4j:ajax>
                <rich:column sortBy="#{nod.priorityName.value}">
                    <f:facet name="header">#{lbl.search_results_priority_flag}</f:facet>
                    <h:graphicImage url="/resources/images/arrowup.png"
                                    rendered='#{nod.priorityName.value.equals("Y")}'
                                    style="width : 12%;" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>...</rich:column>
                <rich:column>...</rich:column>
            </rich:extendedDataTable>
            <rich:contextMenu id="contextMenu" target="node_table" mode="ajax" rendered="#{loginBean.auth.userAccesToCorporateSearchEdit}">
                <rich:menuItem id="menuItem1"
                               label="#{lbl.task_list_context_menu_update_action}"
                               render="popupUpdateContext" mode="ajax"
                               actionListener="#{searchBean.updateNodeStatusToOrderSubm()}"
                               oncomplete="if (#{empty searchBean.updateNodeStatus} ) {#{rich:component('errorPopup')}.show()} else {#{rich:component('errorPopup')}.hide()}" />

                <rich:menuItem label="Edit" render="popupContent"
                               action="#{searchBean.navigate('solutionManagement')}" mode="ajax" />
            </rich:contextMenu>
        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

The problem is the following: When the page loads for the first time, everything works great. Both the search_results_form_service and the contextMenu render. But, if I press again the search commandButton, the contextMenu does not get rendered. Additionaly, from the developer tools I get the following:

[image]
Everything works great again if I refresh the page. I also tried to render all components (render="@all") when pressing the commandButton, but although the contextMenu works, the search_results_form_service does not get rendered.

Comment: What version of RichFaces are you using? This should be fixed in 4.5

Comment: @Makhiel I am using 4.3.7.